# Cannot Authenticate using OAuth 2.0 in Google Calendar (v3) API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am attempting to create Google Calendar events as per the code given at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607465/need-good-example-google-calendar-api-in-javascript/11622475#11622475). I've narrowed the probem down to an authentication issue in the following call:

```js
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
```

which does not return an access token. The returned auth object looks like this:

```
client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", cookie_policy: undefinederror: "immediate_failed", error_subtype: "access_denied"expires_at: "1432593971"expires_in: "86400"g_user_cookie_policy: undefinedissued_at: "1432507571"response_type: "token"scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"state: ""
```

I know my calendar configuration is correct (i.e. client_id) because as I can pull events and place them into a list [see example](http://www.burrenlowlands.org/burrenlowlands/events.html). This is because reading events doesn't require OAuth 2.0 - it only requires a public api key.

Furthermore, I am able to create events programatically using [this Java API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)
by supplying only my client_id. Notice the magic button near the bottom which offers to authorize requests using OAuth 2.0. When I enable this everything works fine. So the question is how is this done programatically in a JavaScript/browser environment?

Answer (score 1):

I had discovered that popups were blocked in my browser and this prevented the authentication process from completing. Once I enabled popups, the process was able to complete successfully. Doh! The code was complete and OK after all.

Answer (score 0):

Wierd. Looks like Google doesn't like your credentials.

1. Have you remembered to call `gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey)` before trying `gapi.auth.authorize()`?
2. Are `apiKey` and `clientId` both defined and in scope? If you're not sure, try sticking `alert(apiKey + '\n' + clientId)` or `console.log(apiKey, clientId)` in the same function.

Comment: I've created a simple running example [here](http://creativecomputerlab.com/simplecalendar.html) which pulls events but cannot insert them. It runs automatically when loaded. Check the console output for results. Everything has been double-checked as suggested by @j-da. Also, I've added the service account email address to the list of calendar users and gave it full permissions.