# Create a Recurrent Calendar Event with HTML

Tags: html, http, google-calendar-api

I'm looking for a way to create a reccurent event in a calendar with a http request in a anchor html's element. I saw this method in other question, and it's work:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=Example%20Event&dates=20131124T010000Z/20131124T020000Z&details=Event%20Details%20Here&location=123%20Main%20St%2C%20Example%2C%20NY">Add to gCal</a>
```

Then, I look in the Google API, and find this:

```
"recurrence": [
"RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20110701T170000Z",]
```

Obviously, I cannot put that in the anchor, but works like a clue.
Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to take a look at: [Need good example: Google Calendar API in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607465/need-good-example-google-calendar-api-in-javascript/11622475#11622475)

Then you can your `recurrence` key into `resource` variable to the example in the link.