# Using google API with javascript - how to include request body

Tags: javascript, rest, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

In order to use events:update as described in https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update , I need to include a request body (and within it supply an events resource). Would anyone know how to do this using Javascript code?

Comment: Try and check the solution from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607465/need-good-example-google-calendar-api-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Please try JS code available at https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update#try-it (Open JavaScript tab).

*You can put request parameters in execute function.